# (OLE DB) Execute SQL Task - Using output parameters

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, oledb

I'm trying to use "Execute SQL Task" in SSIS to get a value to be stored in a user variable.
The documentation says to use '?' as a placeholder for parameters in the query but when I do I get a syntax error trying to parse the query.
So the query is like this:

```
SELECT ? = AVG(Score) FROM Scorecards
```

I've also tried adding OUTPUT after the '?'. All examples I can find for having an output parameter are similar to

```
EXEC ? = MyStoredProc param1, param2, ...
```

This isn't of any use though since I'm not using a stored proc. The use of the parameter seems similar though so why won't SSIS take it for a select statement?

Comment: I can't find an example in my code, but I'm sure you also have to use the Parameter Mapping and/or Result Set to get the data to the user variable.

Comment: Yes, I've also added to Parameter Mapping though SSIS isn't getting that far. It gives me a syntax error when I press "Parse Query" to check if it think the statement is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the ResultSet property to Single Row, then amend your query to something like:

```
select avg(score) as AvgScore from ScoreCards
```

Then in the Result Set pane, click Add, set the Result Name to AvgScore, and your variable to Variable Name (for example, User::AvgScore).

Comment: I tried this. While it does execute successfully the variable is not updated in the variables window when it hits a breakpoint after the task.

Comment: The variable value doesn't update in that window.  You'll be able to to check the value if you add a watch on the variable and open the Watch or Locals window during execution.

Comment: I was using an ODBC driver and found using the number 1 as the Result Name worked instead of entering the column alias. Just in case that helps anyone out there :)